# Optimizar ações da Firebase Realtime Database e Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

Como é que eu posso otimizar a experiência do usuário e a fluidez da aplicação quando estou, por exemplo, a ler dados da Firebase Database ou até fazendo download de Files da Storage? Usando runnable's para lidar com os processos ou existem outras formas mais eficientes para o fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, infelizmente quando temos que utilizar dados vindo da WEB não tem como manter uma fluidez dentro do aplicativo se a internet do usuário não for rápida, mas quando trabalho com firebase normalmente temos os listeners escutando o servidor da google e quando é alterado ele altera a interface do usuário, caso seja a primeira vez que o usuário está entrando naquela tela ai talvez seja bom segurar a interface do usuário até carregar as informações necessárias. Outra coisa boa a se fazer seria ter a persistência dos dados do firebase no próprio dispositivo, inclusive o próprio SDK da google faz esse gerenciamento, só olhar a documentação do firebase ou firestore, depende de qual está utilizando!

Answer (score -1):

É interessante manter o usuário informado que o app está sendo carregado. Você pode colocar um Load, para ele não pensar que a aplicação travou. Assim que os dados forem recebidos, você os oculta e seta os dados.

O facebook utiliza este meio:
https://medium.com/mindorks/android-design-shimmer-effect-fa7f74c68a93

Mas você pode utilizar progressBar personalizadas ou de API's
http://www.zoftino.com/android-progressbar-and-custom-progressbar-examples

Particulamente, gosto muito desse:
https://github.com/EyalBira/loading-dots